# How can I get between string with regular expression without starting word and ending word?

Tags: string, expression, between

How can I get between string with regular expression? the result string shouldn't contain starting word and ending word? I searched on google, no answers.

Original string:
http://xxx.168.x.xxx/delete/568b96fb75b2

Expected string:

xxx.168.x.xxx

---

My regular expression are:

1. `//[\s\S]*(?=/d)  result: //xxx.168.x.xxx`
2. `/[\s\S]*(?=/d)  result: //xxx.168.x.xxx`

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you always want to extract IP addresses from URLs in this form you could use the following:

```
[^/]*(?=/delete)
```

It has the advantage that it doesn't depend on lookbehind or capturing groups.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Actually, my original is from a complicated string:
{"Version":"1.0","status":"0","Uri":"
http://xxx.168.x.xxx/delete/568b96fb75b2"}. I tried with yours, the result is /xxx.168.x.xxx. there is a forward slash at the front of the result string.

Comment: It's odd that it has included a slash at the beginning - the [^/] should match anything that isn't a slash. Is there an extra slash at the beginning of your regex? What implementation of regex are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:  `//(.*?\.168\..*?\..*?)/`

Take Python for example:

```
>>> p=re.compile('//(.*?\.168\..*?\..*?)/')
>>> s='http://xxx.168.x.xxx/delete/568b96fb75b2'
>>> p.findall(s)
['xxx.168.x.xxx']
>>> p2=re.compile('//[\s\S]*(?=/d)')
>>> p2.findall(s)
['//xxx.168.x.xxx']
>>> p3=re.compile('[^/]*(?=/delete)')
>>> p3.findall(s)
['xxx.168.x.xxx', '']
```

As you are probably detecting IP address, this one may be better:`//([0-9]*?\.168\.[0-9]*?\.[0-9]*?)/`
In Python:

```
>>> s1='http://192.168.1.1/delete/fjdsafdasfdsa'
>>> p4=re.compile('//([0-9]*?\.168\.[0-9]*?\.[0-9]*?)/')
>>> p4.findall(s1)
['192.168.1.1']
```